# how to sort array of object by using property name in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, object

Same as the title of the question, here is my array of object

```
[▼
    "2022-11-09" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1500 ▶}
    "2022-11-10" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1499 ▶}
    "2022-11-11" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1498 ▶}
    "2022-11-13" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1501 ▶}
    "2022-11-14" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1496 ▶}
    "2022-11-15" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1495 ▶}
    "2022-11-12" => null
    "2022-11-17" => null
    "2022-11-20" => null
    "2022-11-26" => null
    "2022-11-27" => null
  ]
```

i want to sort that array of object by using its property name, but i dont know how to do that, anyone know how to do that ????

Comment: @M Andre Juliansyah please share your code here !!

Comment: thank you for your respond @RachnaGajjar, but it only that object that all i want to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't that hard of you took a look at the laravel [documentation for collections](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby), and it's `sortBy` method.

You can do it like this:

```php
$sorted = $collection->sortBy('name');
```

Comment: it doesnt work, can you tell me more ?

Comment: sortby only work if i have the same property key name

Comment: Your question doesn't really provide a lot of information regarding the actual collections. If you could provide more info on the, maybe we could help.

Comment: @vix It would be great if you would only answer this question AFTER it is made clear.  Answering unclear questions does not help Stack Overflow or its researchers.